# Integral of $ \int (\sin(x) + 3)(\cos^2 (x))\,dx $

Tags: integration

In an integral that reads:
$ \int (\sin(x) + 3)(\cos^2 (x))\,dx $   the next step in the answer reads $ \frac {-1}{3}\cos^3x + \frac{3}{2} \int (\cos(2x+1)\,dx  $

I understand the part prior to the plus sign but don't understand exactly what is going on after with the integral. Some kind of double angle rule?

Comment: yes, $2\cos^2(x)-1=\cos(2x)$. So $\cos^2(x)=(1+\cos(2x))/2$

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right, it should be $\frac{3}{2}\int(\cos(2x)+1)\,dx$.

This is because $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2 x-1$, so $\cos^2 x=\frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int (\sin(x) + 3)(\cos^2 (x))dx = \int \sin(x) \cos^2 x \ dx + 3\int \cos^2 x \ dx = -\frac 13\cos^3 x + \frac 32 \int (\cos(2x) + 1) \ dx$$

We're using the identity $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2 x - 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int (\sin(x) + 3)(\cos^2 (x))dx\\  
\int (\sin(x) \cos^2 (x))+\int (3\cos^2(x))dx$$
and you can use the trigonometric identity $$ \cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$$ for the second integral. For the first integral, your answer is obtained by substiting $\cos(x)=u$ and so $-\sin(x)dx=du$.